# How to filter data in PHP/MySQL by day?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP script which users submit a post and saves in to the database; I'm storing the date it was posted using time(). I'm trying to figure out a way to filter my data by day. I have a while loop which is returning all the posts that user made which is ordered by date, however what I'm looking to do is have headings of a date for e.g. 10 December 2011 and only have posts that was submitted on that day. I want it only to display the heading if there is data for that day.

Thanks a lot.

EDIT:

Here is my while loop at the moment:

```
$get_posts = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `userid` = '$name[id]' ORDER BY `date` DESC" );
while( $userpost = mysql_fetch_assoc( $get_posts ) )
{
    echo $userpost[ 'post' ];
}
```

But somehow before the loop I need to display the date heading the post or posts was submitted. I'm thinking it would need to be a loop outside of the current loop but I have no idea how to go about it.

Comment: You want to **filter**, not order.

Comment: `time()` returns an integer. What's your column type?

Comment: The column type is an integer. But as for the date it will not be fixed. As the dates will depend on what day the user posted on. Therefore I want it to display the day headings depending on when the user posted and only display the headings if they did.

Comment: Is the time() function you are using from PHP or MySQL? What is the data-type of the DB column where you are keeping the time info?

Comment: Since you have mentioned in a comment above that the column type is integer, I assume that you are using the PHP's time() function to store the UNIX timestamp, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have mentioned in one of your comments to the question that the DB column is of type integer. And so I assume you are storing the UNIX timestamp in the column. From what I understand, you are looking to display something like:

```
DATE HEADING 1
- data
- data

DATE HEADING 2
- data
- data
```

And if that is correct, this code snippet might help:

```
$rs = mysql_query('SELECT `column1`, `column2`, FROM_UNIXTIME(`the_time_column`, \'%d %M %Y\') AS `date_value`
FROM `your_table`
ORDER BY `the_time_column`');
$old = '';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
    $new = $row['date_value'];
    if ($new != $old) { // marks the beginning of a new heading
        echo 'heading = ' . $new;
    }
    // start displaying data under the heading
    echo $row['column1'];
    echo $row['column2'];
    // finish displaying data

    $old = $new;
}
```

Please note that I've used dummy column and table names, so please replace them with the actuals. Also, the above snippet will display heading in ascending order of date. To show in reverse, add DESC at the end of the query.

Hope the above helps!

Comment: That is definitely the answer I was looking for. However as for displaying the heading, how would I get it depending on what the day is? I would need the headings to be created using the `date` column as this has the stored unix timestamp

Comment: For e.g: Say someone posted 4 things on the 9th December 2011 it would display 9th December 2011 and the 4 posts under it.

Comment: @JackWillmor, I'm sorry but I couldn't understand your comment above. I've no knowledge of your DB and application. What do you mean by "how would I get it depending on what the day is? I would need the headings to be created using the date column as this has the stored unix timestamp"? You may display whatever you may need instead of `$new` in the heading `echo`.

Comment: @JackWillmor, I'm sorry I didn't read your 2nd comment. I think my code snippet will give you precisely what you need. That is 09 December 2011 followed by the 4 posts under it. The only change that you need to do is replace `echo 'heading = ' . $new` with just `echo $new`. That should work! And don't forget to put in <br> or whatever to give more structure to the output

Comment: I am sorry for explaining so poorly. Well the headings are the dates when the posts were posted. Such as 9 December 2011. I don't understand what `date_value` is?

Comment: No problem @JackWillmor. The `date_value` is a user-defined column that is calculated as `FROM_UNIXTIME(the_time_column, "%d %M %Y")`. This will give you the output in your heading format that is 09 December 2011. The %d gives the date, %M gives month name and %Y gives the year. You will just need to replace `the_time_column` with your date column. Please read more on FROM_UNIXTIME here - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime

Comment: I understand thank you. I tried running the code and I get an error:
Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Here is my code:
`$get_post = mysql_query( "SELECT post, date, userid, FROM_UNIXTIME(date, \'%d %M %Y\') AS date_value FROM posts WHERE userid = '$name[id]' ORDER BY date DESC" );`

Comment: That warning means that there is some error with the query and it didn't execute. The problem are the back-slashes (I had put it because my query was enclosed in single-quotes) and I think also might be in the way $name[id] is called. Can you please use this - `$get_post = mysql_query( "SELECT post, date, userid, FROM_UNIXTIME(date, '%d %M %Y') AS date_value FROM posts WHERE userid = '" . $name['id'] . "' ORDER BY date DESC" );

Answer (score 1):

You get that right from the database, i.e.:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable 
WHERE 
   DAY(yourDateField)='15' AND 
   MONTH(yourDateField)='10' AND 
   YEAR(yourDateField)='2011'
;
```

or better yet, directly, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable 
WHERE yourDateFieldld=2011-12-10;
```

Depends how you store the data in your DB.

In any case, this should be done in the database, not PHP

Comment: Sorry I don't think I explained clearly. I don't know what the date will be as it will display the data in a while loop. Something like:
10 December 2011
- data 
- data

9 December 2011
- data
- data

Comment: Well, that I understand, it's just the way you call that from PHP, nothing more. You  create a prepared query and then insert the dates on each loop, execute it and get the result. Or, if you have several dates, you can use BETWEEN as was suggested on those dates. Depends on your use case

Comment: But it all will depend if the user posted on that day which will show the headings with their posts under it. If they didn't post on that day then nothing will be shown

Comment: Well, I still don't see how that is relevant or how it changes what I'm suggesting. You probably need to edit your question and describe the problem in more detail. Because if I understand your comment, that's exactly what you'll get.

Answer (score 0):

You could use BETWEEN.

Have a look at [The MySQL Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)